# how to get friends birthday in v2.0 facebook API - any alternate way

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I need help.
We all know that in v2.0 all permissions of `friends_*` are removed.

But still is there any way to get birth date of friends who also use your app?
I am using below permissions:

```
&scope=public_profile,email,user_friends
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you get any answer for this? had you contacted fb people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Graph API v2.0, all `friends_*` permissions have been removed (as you wrote): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

So, there's no way to get the `birthday` of the User's friends via the Graph API anymore.

Comment: Thankx for reply. My application gonn break due this changes after Apr 2015.All functionality is depend on birthdates.

Comment: Well, you could file a bug report with FB to get an official quote on the topic, but I highly doubt that this will be successful.

Comment: What does your app do?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if this could help you but i think it could be worth a try. there is the possibility to subscribe to facebooks friend calender api via a link: e.g "webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?uid=10001111111&key=AQDcQxnFPn7Sb9WridI" - you can add this to google calender, ical or other. via this subscription you can receive all the info you need. as we have the same issue with our application we will try to figure out a way how to retrieve and use this information. anyways i dont know if it is an option for your app.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. Did you have any success trying it? Thanks