# Facebook Open Graph API location search for all friends photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to write a Facebook Open Graph query that returns the following: all public photos that have been posted by any Facebook friend that is geolocated in a certain area.

According to [Facebook's documentation for the latest API version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1), I thought that a good start would be to use the /search endpoint as follows:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    type=location&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```

However, when I try to test this in the Graph API explorer, it returns an error saying that location search has been deprecated in v.2.1, despite the fact that it appears in the documentation. Conversely, the Platform Changelog document does seem to indicate that since v2.0 there are two changes that will prove to be a problem for my desired query:

1. Public Post Search is no longer available
2. /me/friends no longer returns all friends but rather only returns app friends

Finally, to add to my confusion, there is an iPhone app called [Scope](https://www.scopemedia.com/Scope__photos_fast,_by_location.html) that does exactly this: it allows users to create social media filters using a set of friends and/or a location and displays Facebook content that matches those criteria. Is this app working on borrowed time and will it become non-functional when Open Graph v1.0 is shut down next April?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to your last question is yes...apps like Scope are working on borrowed time. Last April facebook launched v2.0 and said that only existing apps would be allowed to use v1.0 and that calling 1.0 after April will behave the same way as calling 2.0.

You can read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions
and here: 
[stack overflow question re: friends birthdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303376/how-to-get-friends-birthday-in-v2-0-facebook-api-any-alternate-way)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I feared. I was hoping that I was reading it wrong.

Comment: no problem. i was pretty surprised when i learned about this. it makes it much harder to have an app go viral on facebook.